# waitin closes browsers for all projects that are building

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, watin

I'm having an issue running WatiN under CruiseControl.net, where on a .forceclose, watin is closing all open browser instances. I have multiple projects running under cruisecontrol, and its not uncommon for some of those projects to be building and testing at the same time. There has been more than one occasion where watin will close the browser window for a different project, causing it to fail. In my local tests, creating my watin instance under a new process fixes this issue. But running under cruisecontrol, when doing this, I lose my IE object:

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

- Running CC.net as a service
- CC.Net server is Windows 2003
- IE6

Any thoughts?

Comment: Do you use IE6 in your local test?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember, WatiN won't close a browser unless you specifically closed them, like:

```
ie.Close();
```

You still might want to set/check you browser `AutoClose` property:

```
ie.AutoClose = false;
```